# How to rename the breadcrumb?

Tags: navigation, breadcrumb

How can I rename the Breadcrumb for page title **'HOME'** in SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 1):

The breadcrumb is using the site and page title by using SiteMapProviders. You can check this in the masterpage.
You can rename the site/page title from 'Home' to something you like.